# Repeating array... Thats not supposed to repeat?

Tags: php

For some reason this array keeps repeating the 1st line onto the 2nd line and the 1st and 2nd line onto the 3rd line, and so on and so on.

```
unset ($grade); $grade = array();
foreach ($row as $grade => $value) {
  if (substr($grade, 0,1)== "y") {
  if ($grade == "y1") {if ($value == "x") {$grades[] = "1";}}
  if ($grade == "y2") {if ($value == "x") {$grades[] = "2";}}
  if ($grade == "y3") {if ($value == "x") {$grades[] = "3";}}
  if ($grade == "y4") {if ($value == "x") {$grades[] = "4";}}
  if ($grade == "y5") {if ($value == "x") {$grades[] = "5";}}
  if ($grade == "y6") {if ($value == "x") {$grades[] = "6";}}
  if ($grade == "y7") {if ($value == "x") {$grades[] = "7";}}
}}
$grades_string = implode(", ", $grades);
```

The dB rows are titled y1, y2 etc.
 I can show someone a link with the example of what I mean the error is if need be.

Comment: Why not show the link right away?

Comment: I didnt think we were allowed to post links?
http://www.illism.com/Science/index.php?cat=02&do=Search&id=0

Comment: Sure we are - it helps a lot.

Answer (score 4):

It's becouse you create `$grade = array();` but you want create `$grades = array();`

Correct this syntax mistake and it then should work fine.

**Also** you can move `if ($value == "x")` to `if (substr($grade, 0,1)== "y")` this make your code cleaner and faster. In your case:

```
if (substr($grade, 0,1)== "y" && $value == "x") {
    if ($grade == "y1") {$grades[] = "1";}
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just rewrite the loop to be more readable/make more sense, you still need you to clear up what's wrong and then I'll update my answer.

```
foreach ($row as $grade => $value) {
    if (substr($grade, 0,1)== "y" AND $value == "x") {
        if ($grade == "y1") {$grades[] = "1";}
        elseif ($grade == "y2") {$grades[] = "2";}
        elseif ($grade == "y3") {$grades[] = "3";}
        elseif ($grade == "y4") {$grades[] = "4";}
        elseif ($grade == "y5") {$grades[] = "5";}
        elseif ($grade == "y6") {$grades[] = "6";}
        elseif ($grade == "y7") {$grades[] = "7";}
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your code and the same issue

Comment: Like I said, my code is only an optimized version of your code.